# Content Porter Package Import Errors

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2013

I just finished applying patch Tridion 2011 SP1 HR2.
Trying to import a package and i get these dependency errors, can anybody help Is this installation problem or a package problem?

- The dependency item with URL "/webdav//Zip.tmt" does not exist on the
  import server. Create it or skip import of all items that depend on
  it.
- The dependency item with URL "/webdav//JPEG.tmt" does not exist on
  the import server. Create it or skip import of all items that depend
  on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd look into configuration first, specifically for Multimedia Types for `Zip` and `JPEG` (because of the `.tmt` extension). It might not be the package itself (these typically export fine), but what's missing in the destination environment.

I'd expect JPEG to be out-of-the-box per [SDL Live Content](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_824A2979F64649359BA4FDDA9C0F7463) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)), though.

Comment: I have added multimedia types but I have more missing items with "tgp" and "tas" extensions, what are those referring to?

Comment: Ok, I found it, these are security groups, I added missing security groups and now error related to security group. Next errors are related to some mising components of ".tas" extension, These are "ApprovalStatus", how can I add new ApprovalStatus?

Comment: In the Administration screen you should have a button "Approval Status" - define them there.

Comment: The good news is after setting these up your environments will match better and you won't get prompted for these items. :-)

Comment: Why do I need to create these missing items? I thought content porter import process will automatically create missing things. Is it not how it works?

Comment: Yes and no since you can control dependencies on export and import. It's automatic to the extent that you choose. For example, you might not want schema updates or new items in an environment.

Comment: You also may not have the permission to create the items that are missing, even if they are included on the package. An example is if you port a component that is based on a non-existent schema. Both may be included in the package, and if you aren't allowed to create schemas then the import will fail.

Comment: As a follow-up, note that SDL Web 8.5 and later have a Privileges feature that gives groups access to manage things like Multimedia Types and Workflow Approval Statuses in case non-admin users ("application managers") need to manage these. See my [blog post series on Privileges](https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/b/blog-posts/posts/sdl-web-privileges-1-of-3) for background info.