# How to move content present in one Publication to another Publication with in two CME's

Tags: 2013-sp1, web8.5, content-porter-2013

[image]I need to move some contents and Schemas present in Publication A in CME ONE (Tridion 2013) to Publication B in CME TWO (SDL Web 8.5).

I tried using Content Porter but it's resulting in multiple errors like Publication A not found in CME TWO.

I cannot change the Publication name in CME TWO.

Let me know your thoughts?

Comment: When you say mulitple errors - I assume you mane all errors relate to publication(s), or organisational items not existing?

Comment: You mention you cannot change the Publication name in CME TWO, but what about changing it before export in CME ONE? Keep in mind it is a temporary change, you need it for just the export or import, so only for a few minutes. If both CMEs have Publication ONE and TWO, you will have to rename both Publications temporarily.

Comment: Typically Schemas and Components aren't in the same Publication. Errors might be related to Publication context and where the items live. You may want to use the BluePrinting move up/down features along with Publication context settings in Content Porter to adjust where the final Schemas and Components should live in CM(E) TWO.

Answer (score 6):

Have you checked the documentation?

- You can use explicit transfer mappings: https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Content%20Porter%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-2587308B-86CB-4AA2-BDA3-E740A1349418

  - if this is a permanent situation then you would likely follow this route as you can save out to config
- Or you could even consider temporarily changing the name of the Publication in the source or target *[1]* environment prior to exporting or importing respectively

  - if this is a one-off situation this could be the quickest assuming you have total control of the environment during the import/export period

[1] *I do realise you state you're unable to update the Publication Name in CME TWO - what about CME ONE?*

Answer (score 4):

Just seen the question update - seems to be items specifically with the `.tmt` extension - which I'm guessing are the `Multimedia types`.

Do you have permission to see/export and/or see/import these item types - typically in one of the topmost publications and accessible by admin?

Maybe create one of the specific `Multimedia Types` in the target publication and see if the error for that item is removed?

( reference to [Content Porter Package Import Errors](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3493/content-porter-package-import-errors/18855#18855) )

Answer (score 2):

I want to point that there is another option. Content porter works on principle where you export package from one publication and import it into another.

**Keeping this in mind, there is no restriction where you cannot change package by hand.**

So you can export from one environment, change package by changing webdavs into it to map second env, and then import it.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using the mapping functionality provided. It's simply to do a search/replace I understand - but it's equally as easy to accidentally screw-up your export and the closer to PRD you are - the bigger an issue that's going to be.

Comment: Yes I Agree. Plus there is always an option to use intermediate env. Export from a to b, then rename publication in b and then do export from b to c environment.

Answer (score 1):

You could port them from 2013 to 8.5 "as is", then move them in the BluePrint using Promote/Demote functionality.

Comment: Assuming both Publications exist on the target environment and they are in the same BluePrint. Even then, it may be quite a hassle to promote/demote a whole bunch of items.

Comment: Tried porting complete publication to 8.5 resulting in errors. Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.ImportExportException: Item '/webdav//Javascript%20old.tmt' cannot be imported because it is absent on import TCM and its content was not exported to the package.